# How to implement a PauliSparseOp object in qiskit if its non unitary?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, unitarity

I have a PauliSparseOp object whose matrix is non-unitary, is there a way I can implement this on qiskit? It is written in terms of sum of tensor products of I,X,Y and Z operators.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "implement in Qiskit"? You can decompose any 2^n x 2^n dimensional matrix in terms of I,X,Y,Z operators if you allow complex coefficients. Qiskit's `SparsePauliOp.from_operator` should be able to handle this.

Comment: I mean that I have created my hamiltonian through SparsePauliOp and it looks like this : 
SparsePauliOp(['IIII', 'IIIZ', 'IIXX', 'IIYY', 'IIZI', 'IXXI', 'IYYI', 'IZII', 'XIIX', 'XXII', 'YIIY', 'YYII', 'ZIII'],
              coeffs=[ 2. +0.j, -0.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j, -0.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j,
 -0.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j,  3.5+0.j, -0.5+0.j])
Now I want to apply this operator as a gate on a 4 qubit quantum circuit. (My final goal is to calculate this matrix's eigvalues/eigvectors). But this matrix is non unitary.

Comment: Qiskit only supports applying unitary operations on qubits (non-unitary are generally also possible but would require e.g. measurements and resets in addition). If you're looking to apply e.g. the HHL algorithm on a non-unitary matrix, the approach is usually to embed the matrix in a larger matrix which is unitary.